# SQL get fields which are null/empty for each record returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below query which I'm using to retrieve records which have at least one of the following columns set as `NULL` or `''`:

- MainImage
- Summary
- Description

  ```
  DECLARE @missingFields varchar(100)
  SET @missingFields = ''

  SELECT 

  c.[UnitReference] as 'UnitRef',
  t.[NodeName] as 'Property',
  @missingFields as 'Field/s missing'

  FROM [DetailPage] d
  INNER JOIN [CRM] c
  ON d.ItemID = c.ItemID
  INNER JOIN 
  [Tree] t
  ON d.[ID] = t.[ID]

  WHERE (ISNULL(d.MainImage, '') = '' OR ISNULL(d.Summary,'') = '' OR ISNULL(d.[Description],'') = '')
  AND c.[IsListed] = 1 AND c.[IsMarketed] = 1
  ```

This returns the data I want however I also need to build up a string which lists which of the columns is null or empty for the returned record, e.g. `"Main Image is empty, Description is empty"` when a record has empty `MainImage` and `Description` columns.

I've tried:

```
@missingFields = CASE WHEN ISNULL(MainImage, '') = '' THEN 'Main image is null' ELSE '' END -- etc...
```

But I can't include this with the data retrieval operations. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Will one of the fields always be null? Also can multiple fields be null?

Comment: why is a variable needed?  can't you just use the case statement?  Are you wanting reocrd with up to 3 different status?  something like `Case when isnull(d.mainimage,'')='' then 'Main Image is Null ' end
& case when isnull(d.Description,'')='' then 'Description is Null ' end as [Fields Missing]`?

Comment: A field is not guaranteed to be null. Multiple fields can be null for a record yes.

Comment: Why are you using ISNULL here? You have made this nonSARGable. A simple d.MainImage IS NULL OR....would be simpler to read and maintain. I think you are trying to do something like a delimited list of values for multiple columns that are NULL??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT c.[UnitReference] AS 'UnitRef',
           t.[NodeName] AS 'Property',
           ( CASE
                 WHEN d.MainImage IS NULL
                 THEN 'Main Image is Null, '
                 WHEN d.MainImage = ''
                 THEN 'Main Image is Empty, '
                 ELSE ''
             END )+
             ( CASE
                WHEN d.Summary IS NULL
                THEN 'Summary is Null, '
                WHEN d.Summary = ''
                THEN 'Summary is Empty, '
                ELSE ''
            END )+
            ( CASE
                WHEN d.[Description] IS NULL
                THEN 'Description is Null, '
                WHEN d.[Description] = ''
                THEN 'Description is Empty, '
                ELSE ''
            END ) AS MissingFields
    FROM [DetailPage] d
    INNER JOIN [CRM] c
    ON d.ItemID = c.ItemID
    INNER JOIN [Tree] t
    ON d.[ID] = t.[ID]
    WHERE( d.MainImage IS NULL OR d.MainImage = '' )
     OR ( d.Summary IS NULL OR d.Summary = '' )
     OR ( d.[Description] IS NULL OR d.[Description] = '' )
     AND c.[IsListed] = 1
     AND c.[IsMarketed] = 1
```

Comment: Hmm.  I think this is basically the right approach, but what happens with this particular query if some of the columns of interest are null / empty and others are not?  Don't you then get `MissingFields` evaluating to `NULL`?

Comment: @John Yes that's what I'm currently getting

Comment: The `CASE` expressions need an `ELSE` clause that yields a blank or empty string.

Comment: my bad forgot the else

Comment: Cheers, this works! Had to modify the where clause though as it wasn't filtering `IsListed` and `IsMarketed`.